# Python standalone exe file with Pyinsatller

Tags: python-3.x, dll, executable, pyinstaller, vcredist

I have written a GUI python script (with Tkinter), I want to export it in "exe" format, compatible with all versions of windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10)

I am using [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to do so. Also, my code is compatible with Python 3, all versions. (3.5, 3.4 ...)

**Some explanation:**

Using **Pyinstaller + Python 3.5**, I can't install the output Exe file in some windows. Because of this error that occurs in some older versions of windows: "The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll". Well, I searched and found out that the error is because some **dll** files don't exists. And the solution: User should install Microsoft VC redist 2015.

I downgraded my compilation with Python 3.4, the problem seems to be solved.

**But the problem:**

Using **Pyinstaller + Python 3.4**, I can install the ouput Exe file (I tested Exe file in Win Xp & 7 in Virtual Machine), but I'm not sure if there won't be any problem for none of my users.

In other words, I guess output of Pyinstaller for Python 3.4 contains all needed dll files, so no need to install extra MS vc redist, but how to become sure of it?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: As long as it works on a system, you can assume that it will work in all with a similar configuration. You can never be sure that it will work everywhere. Even the biggest software companies fail to do that all the time. A good idea is to identify a test user group and ask them to run your software.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just installed VM and tested the application on raw Windows XP, 7, 8 and 8.1.
There was no problem on those systems, so decided to publish the application.